# Adding a Event to Google Calendar app using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar, web-testing

I'm having a problem with HTML code.
I'm trying to add a Invitation event to Calendar app using HTML by using anchor tag and href () so when I code it like following:

```
<a href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r?cmd=addevent&amp;t=g&amp;calid=primary&amp;text=My%20Event&amp;details=This%20is%20a%20test%20event.&amp;startdt=2023-08-10T08:00:00&amp;enddt=2023-08-10T09:00:00">Add to Calendar</a>
```

This code will create a link that, when clicked, will open Google Calendar and add an event with the following details:

Title: My Event
Description: This is a test event.
Start date and time: 2023-08-10T08:00:00
End date and time: 2023-08-10T09:00:00

But issue here is, It is just opening the https://calendar.google.com/ site and doing nothing.

I tried changing data format, time zones and adding moment.js. But no use.

Comment: You cannot add events directly to a calendar without proper user credentials. I am very surprized that pasting the href into the browser address bar opens my Google calendar at the specified date (time points actually at 16:00, probably the *current date/time*). When using your HTML (`<a href=...>`) in Codepen a security errors is issued, which I would expect accessing the calendar from an outside link. It's highly dubious that Google mail accepts access like this without logon credentials. You may have stumbled over a massive security leak. @tamtejszystan indeed accesses the calendar...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a link, you could try using JavaScript to open the calendar event window.

html:

```html
<button id="addToCalendar">Add to Calendar</button>
```

javascript:

```js
document.getElementById("addToCalendar").addEventListener("click", function() {
    window.open("https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r?cmd=addevent&t=g&calid=primary&text=My%20Event&details=This%20is%20a%20test%20event.&startdt=2023-08-10T08:00:00&enddt=2023-08-10T09:00:00");
});
```

And make sure your Google Calendar settings are configured to allow external event additions.

Comment: Check my comment at the OP question. Your code works just like pasting the href into the address bar, but the calendar opens at the current date and time (2023-08-10:16:00) after changing the date to 2023-08-11 in the link. Fun to see it happen, but dubious that it works without asking for any logon credentials.

Comment: @RenevanderLende At first, I thought this was too trivial to be a threat that Google might not be aware of. But then, I returned to this piece of code, saw your comment, and you've just strengthened my feeling that it might be worth reporting after all

Comment: I think it is because I usually don't logout of Google  (like many other people, I guess). I think the above method seems to work as I am *already* logged in. This would mean that any Google app opens directly using the API when a user is already logged in. While a developer may not be able to post anything in any app (meeting, email, photo, etc) it does mean, however, that someone can open a Google app in a users' browser without credentials. Essentially IMHO, the first line of defence has been breached/circumvented. At least interesting to question Google about this (and warn people).